# How to check if an object is a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is there a reliable way to check if an object is a Vue.js component?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), as following code:

```
var isVueComp = vuecomp instanceof Vue
```

If it `isVueComp` is true, it is a Vue.js componeny otherwise not.

You can also use [vuecomp.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), which  will return reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object.

Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/n057tkqm/1/).

Answer (score 10):

Like Saurabh wrote, `instanceof` is probably the best way to be sure. However, in case you don't want to import Vue just for this purpose, you could use `this._isVue`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check if a an object is a Vue component, as in 2020l, is probably the **_isVue** property of the component, which, in case of the given object being a Vue.js component, exists as key-value at the root of the object and returns true.

```
Const isVueComponent = [VUE_COMPONENT_OBJECT]._isVue
```